# Assign a delegate for UITableViewCell during initialization

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, delegates, uicollectionview

I am building a custom `UITableView` to add in to my ViewController. In this `UITableView` my first cell has some items so I want them to scroll horizontally, so I added a `UICollectionView` inside the first cell of my `UITableView`. Every thing is working fine. Now I want my `UIViewController` in which I am adding `UITableView` to be set as the `dataSource` for my `UICollectionView`. Here is my `UITableView` class code.

The problem is inside `-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method we are setting `cell.delegate` and `cell.dataSource` objects This delegate and datasource needs to be assigned while the cell is being initialized otherwise collectionView delegate methods run before they are assigned and hence they are `nil` when they are called.

Here is `UIViewController` Code

```
@interface MyViewController ()<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,MyTableViewCellDelegate,MyTableViewCellDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) MyTableView *tableView;
@end
```

@implementation MyViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //TODO: Move uiviewcontroller view appearance in NBUIAppearance class. - Kedar Inamdar
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self setupSubViews];
    [self.presenter viewIsReady];
}

- (void) setupSubViews {

    // TableView AutoLayout Constraints
    self.tableView = [[MyTableView alloc] initWithParentViewController:self];
    self.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;
    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(tableView);
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
    [self.view addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[tableView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[tableView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    //Setting delegate & Datasource for TableView

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(section == 0) return 1;
    return 20;
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
        FirstTableViewCell *cell =  (FirstTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FirstTableViewCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.delegate = self;
        cell.dataSource = self;
        return cell;
    } else{
        SecondTableViewCell *cell = (SecondTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SecondTableViewCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;
    }
}

# pragma Mark - Custom CollectionView DataSource

- (NSInteger) numberOfItems {
    //return something
}

- (id) itemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath{
//    return something
}
```

This is Custom UITableView Code

```
@implementation MyTableView

- (nonnull instancetype) initWithParentViewController:(nonnull UIViewController *)parentViewController {

    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectZero style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    if(self) {
        self.parentViewController = parentViewController;
        [self setupSubViews];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self) {
        [self setupSubViews];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setupSubViews {
    if(!self.parentViewController) {
        return;
    }

    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FirstTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"FirstTableViewCellIdentifier"];
    [self registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SecondTableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SecondTableViewCellIdentifier"];

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

And here is my custom FirstTableViewCell class code. Now the problem is I want to initialize the delegate and dataSource of FirstTableViewCell at the time of its initialization. Otherwise in the `UICollectionView` delegate and dataSource methods, these delegate methods are nil and will not able to fetch the right data.

```
@interface FirstTableViewCell()<UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *myCollectionView;

@end

@implementation FirstTableViewCell

-( instancetype) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]){

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
    [self setupSubviews];
}


-(void) setupSubviews {

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout =  (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.beneficiaryCollectionView.collectionViewLayout;
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(80, 100);
    [self.CollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:MyCollectionViewCellIdentifier];

    self.myCollectionView.delegate = self;
    self.myCollectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.myCollectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor ];
    self.myCollectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegate & DataSource


- (NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
```

// self.dataSource is nil at this point
        return [self.dataSource numberOfItems];
    }

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCollectionViewCellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    id object = [self.dataSource itemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //TODO:  Need to remove
    object = object;
    return cell;
}
```

How to assign `cell.delegate` and `cell.dataSource` object at the time of initialization or before UICollectionView delegate methods gets called?

Comment: in your FirstTableViewCell class already added delegate and datasource again why are you adding in controller?

Comment: ViewController is taking care of UITableViewDelegate and dataSource and also for custom UICollectionViewDataSource. I have added some more code in UiviewController which i forgot to add earlier.

Comment: how are you setting delegate to FirstTableViewCell class, it's a UITableViewCell.

Comment: you should try like this it seems: firstTableViewCell .myCollectionView.delegate = self